# How to deploy Upgradable Smart Contract on Tron Network

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, upgrading, contract-upgrading

I have some time as a developer in ethereum based networks and actually making and deploying a smart contract with openzeppelin is very simple.

The problems start when you go to the Tron network because you know that it is based on the **EVM** but it has its own applications for all the interactions with the blockchain.

I have implemented some smart contracts that I need to be upgradeable because of the logic I am following, but apparently when deploying **Tronbox** it is not compatible with **@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades** and I have not found any library to solve this problem.

This is my code

```
const ExampleToken = artifacts.require("ExampleToken");
const {deployProxy} = require("@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades");

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
    await deployProxy(ExampleToken, [], {deployer});
};
```

And this is the error I get

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/build/components/Provider/index.js:1
> "use strict";var _require=require("../TronWrap"),TronWeb=_require.TronWeb;var wrapper=require("./wrapper");module.exports={wrap:function wrap(provider,options){return wrapper.wrap(provider,options)},create:function create(options){var provider;if(options.provider&&typeof options.provider==="function"){provider=options.provider()}else if(options.provider){provider=options.provider}else{var HttpProvider=TronWeb.providers.HttpProvider;HttpProvider.prototype.send=function(payload){var request=this.prepareRequest(false);try{request.send(JSON.stringify(payload))}catch(error){throw new Error("Invalid Connection (".concat(this.host,")"))}var result=request.responseText;try{result=JSON.parse(result)}catch(e){throw new Error("Invalid Response (".concat(request.responseText,")"))}return result};HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync=function(payload,callback){var request=this.prepareRequest(true);request.onreadystatechange=function(){if(request.readyState===4&&request.timeout!==1){var result=request.responseText;var error=null;try{result=JSON.parse(result)}catch(e){error=new Error("Invalid Response (".concat(request.responseText,")"))}callback(error,result)}};request.ontimeout=function(){throw new Error("Connection Timeout (".concat(this.timeout,")"))};try{request.send(JSON.stringify(payload))}catch(error){callback(new Error("Invalid Connection (".concat(this.host,")")))}return request};provider=new HttpProvider(options.fullHost)}return this.wrap(provider,options)},test_connection:function test_connection(provider,callback){callback(null,true)}};

> TypeError: this.prepareRequest is not a function
> at e.HttpProvider.sendAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/build/components/Provider/index.js:1:873)
> at e.sendAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/build/components/Provider/wrapper.js:1:1544)
> at Object.sendAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/build/components/Migrate/index.js:1:4934)
> at node:internal/util:360:7
> at new Promise ()
> at bound sendAsync (node:internal/util:346:12)